# set JTextArea font

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, fonts

i am trying to change `JTextArea` font by 3 `JComboBoxes` namely font, style and size and a button.
The user will select the desired options from the `JComboBoxes` and click on OK. the `ActionListener` for the OK button is here

```
final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
JPanel  dpanel = new JPanel();
dialog.add(dpanel);
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
String[] fontnames = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();    

JLabel label = new JLabel("         Font                                     Size                   Style");
dpanel.add(label);

final JComboBox font,style,size;
font = new JComboBox(fontnames);
dpanel.add(font);

style = new JComboBox();
style.addItem("Bold");
style.addItem("Italic");
style.addItem("Bold and Italic");
style.addItem("Plain");
dpanel.add(style);

size = new JComboBox();
for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
{
    size.addItem(i);
}
size.setSelectedItem("22");
dpanel.add(size);

JButton button = new JButton("Done");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    String fontvalue = (String) font.getSelectedItem();
    int stylevalue = (Integer) style.getSelectedItem();
    int sizevalue = (Integer) size.getSelectedItem();

    if(style.getSelectedItem().equals("Bold"))
    {
        stylevalue = Font.BOLD;
    }
    else if(style.getSelectedItem().equals("Italic"))
    {
        stylevalue = Font.ITALIC;
    }
    else if(style.getSelectedItem().equals("Bold and Italic"))
    {
        stylevalue = Font.BOLD|Font.ITALIC;
    }
    else
    {
        stylevalue = Font.PLAIN;
    }
    Font areafont = new Font(fontvalue,stylevalue,sizevalue);
    area.setFont(areafont);
    dialog.dispose();        
}
});
dpanel.add(button);
dialog.setTitle("Fonts");
dialog.setSize(400,200);
dialog.setLocation(400,200);
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.setResizable(false);
```

please help me out as it is not working properly. It throws the exception`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer.`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StyleValue is a string and you are trying to cast it as an Integer.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        String fontvalue = (String) font.getSelectedItem();
        int stylevalue = 0;
        int sizevalue = (Integer) size.getSelectedItem();

        if(style.getSelectedItem().equals("Bold"))
        {
            stylevalue = Font.BOLD;
        }
        else if(style.getSelectedItem().equals("Italic"))
        {
            stylevalue = Font.ITALIC;
        }
        else if(style.getSelectedItem().equals("Bold and Italic"))
        {
            stylevalue = Font.BOLD|Font.ITALIC;
        }
        else
        {
            stylevalue = Font.PLAIN;
        }
        Font areafont = new Font(fontvalue,stylevalue,sizevalue);
        //area.setFont(areafont);
        dialog.dispose();        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You define style as

```
style = new JComboBox();
style.addItem("Bold");
style.addItem("Italic");
style.addItem("Bold and Italic");
style.addItem("Plain");
```

But you're retrieving the value using

```
int stylevalue = (Integer) style.getSelectedItem();
```

`getSelectedItem` will return a `String` value, which can't be cast to `int`

Which is entrily strange, because you seem to be ignoring the return value anyway and calculating its result

Answer (score 0):

sizeValue is string and you are casting it into integer. That's the reason of exception. Correct it.

Answer (score 0):

From java doc

```
public Object getSelectedItem()

Returns the current selected item.

If the combo box is editable, then this value may not have been added to the combo box with addItem, insertItemAt or the data constructors.

Returns:
    the current selected Object
```

On this line  `int stylevalue = (Integer) style.getSelectedItem();` in your code you are trying to cast String to int which is throwing exception